# In yii how to find user's id by using email field

Tags: sql, yii

In yii i am developing function.I am checking user entered email id whether it exists in database by query-

```
$record=User1::model()->find(array(
         'select'=>'primaryEmail',
         'condition'=>'PrimaryEmail=:email',
         'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
             );
```

if record exists then i want to retrieve that record's userid and SecurityQuestionId. So how to write search query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$record=User1::model()->find(array(
         'select'=>'id, securityQuestionId, primaryEmail',
         'condition'=>'primaryEmail=:email',
         'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
             );
```

or just

```
$record = User1::model()->findByAttributes(array('primaryEmail' => $_POST['email']));
```

Comment: Thanx sir its working. $record->securityQuestionId gives securityQuestionId. Now i want to display actual question associated with this SecurityQuestionId from Table SecurityQuestion. So how can i  implement this. Please help me...

Comment: @user1764357  all your questions are explained at [Yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/), try to read it :)
For securityQuestionId you need to define relation at your User1 model. Function relations() must contain: `'securityQuestion'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'SecurityQuestion', 'securityQuestionId'),`.
So you can get question by `$record->securityQuestion->question` (`question` is the field of `SecurityQuestion` table)

Comment: When i am trying to access actual securityQuestion by using securityQuestionId,its giving an error as trying to get property of non-object

Comment: In model i have relation as-                                                           public function relations(){return array('securityQuestion'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Securityquestion', 'securityQuestionId'),
  );
  }

Comment: your question model name is 'SecurityQuestion'? so try: `array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'SecurityQuestion', 'securityQuestionId')`
If don't, debug  your action - add `var_dump($record->securityQuestion)` and place code here.

Comment: public function actionCreate(){
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{ $record=User2::model()->find(array('select'=>'userId, securityQuestionId, primaryEmail','condition'=>'primaryEmail=:email','params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
 );if($record===null) {echo "Email invalid";}
 else {echo $record->securityQuestionId;

echo $record->Securityquestion->securityQuestion;}}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20301/discussion-between-driver-by-and-shilpa-kirad)